# Homebrew PHP mysql_conect

Tags: php, mysql, apache, module

I have a project that is using `mysql_connect()`. (I cannot change this to `mysqli`)

I am getting the error: `Call to undefined function mysql_connect()`

I have installed php56 using homebrew
`brew install php56 --with-http24`

I have seen people mentioning the `--with-mysql` flag however this does not exist.

When running
`brew options php56` i see `--without-mysql`

when I run `phpinfo()` I get the following in the Configure Command:

```
./configure --with-mysql-sock=/tmp/mysql.sock' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' ....
```

I also see sections for `mysqli` `mysqlnd` and `pdo_mysql`

and under `Module Authors` I have:

```
MySQL   |   Zeev Suraski, Zak Greant, Georg Richter, Andrey Hristov
```

Any Idea how to get `mysql_connect()` working?

Comment: `mysql` extension is deprecated and removed, forget about it.

Comment: `mysql_query` is dead. You'll have to move to something more modern like PDO.

Comment: Not an option at the moment, Even though it is depreciated it should still be available in 5.6 correct?

Comment: @ShawnNorthrop Continuing to use the MySQL extension is not an option. PHP 5.6 is no longer actively supported, and will no longer receive even security support after December 2018. The extension is permanently removed in PHP 7.0.

Comment: Ok, well I guess there is nothing to be done then.

Comment: I have the exact issue and still trying to found an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a mistake. I opened an issue on GitHub and its fixed now. Please try again. Should work now.

Issue : https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/4133